# Spark - Concatenate pairs of files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I wonder if Spark is suitable for below use case:

I have millions of csv files as pairs. I would like to concatenate each pair of files and output another file (each pair has the same number of rows and different columns, so i would like to join basically but the actual operation is not important for this question). So:

```
a1.csv
a2.csv
b1.csv
b2.csv
...
...
```

becomes:

```
a-concat.csv
b-concat.csv
....
```

I can easily do that in a normal python script with Pandas for example, but it will take very long time. Instead I would like to distribute this with Spark. Normally Spark collects files, create huge dataframes and operate on them which is not the case for this specific problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: just use tools like sed?

Comment: It can be done with any tool on a local computer or single server. The idea is using a distributed computing system such as Spark to be able to parallelise so that the total execution finishes in hours rather than days.

Comment: you can use gnu parallel with sed